# Las Queues interfieren con el usuario?

Tags: laravel, notification, auth, queue

Estoy intentando enviar notificaciones por mail con encolado de tareas. En primer lugar, el método Mail de la clase de la notificación lo tengo así:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->success()
        ->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'))
        ->subject('Mensaje recibido de '.auth()->user()->name.'.')
        ->greeting('HOLA, '.$notifiable->name)
        ->line($this->mensaje['mensaje'])
        ->action('Acceder a la web', url('/'))
        ->line('Gracias por usar la aplicación')
        ->salutation('Saludos');
}
```

Esto funciona perfectamente cuando la notificación se envía directamente, sin usar Queues.
Sin embargo, cuando intento usar colas, la tarea falla, y el mensaje no se envía. En la tabla de `failed_jobs` me aparece la descripción de la excepción cómo E`rrorException: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`.

Si elimino el método `subject()` las tareas encoladas se ejecutan. Es como si, a la hora de encolar la tarea, no reconociera el funcionamiento de `auth()->user()`. Sin embargo, si envío la notificación sin encolar, sí funciona.

¿Qué problema hay con este dato, y como puedo resolverlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto auth() se resuelve "en tiempo real", por lo que no puede pasarse a una cola. Lo suyo, en este caso, es pasar el nombre a la clase de la notificación desde el controlador.

```
$mensaje = [
   'remitente_id' => auth()->id(),
   'remitente_name' => auth()->user()->name,
   'destinatario_id' => $request->destinatario,
   'mensaje' => $request->mensaje,
];
```

Así en la clase de la notificación lo puedes recuperar por la variable indicada:

```
->subject('Mensaje recibido de '.$this->mensaje['remitente_name'].'.')
```

Comment: Aja. Ahora lo veo, y funciona como dices. Gracias